# Creating Pages deployment failed

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

upon uploading my files into repository in GitHub, no link of the website in pages section on the settings created and the repository shows error in the deployment to GitHub pages ( the 3rd step of processing ). can anyone help me?

I have deleted the repository and recreated another one with the same files, but nothing changed, the error still happening.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages can sometimes be a bit tricky to set up, but I'll try to help you troubleshoot the problem.

Here are the following steps that may help you fix your **potential issue** to make your website **Live**:

**1. Is `index.html` in the Root of the repo?** First, double-check if the `index.html` is at the **ROOT** of the folder or repo. Because GitHub pages take the `index.html` file as an entry point for your website.

**2. Check If you are using the correct branch for the Publishing website on GitPages?**

**3. If you are using any framework or library like React JS, Next JS, Vue JS, or Angular JS, you need to double-check if the build process is set correctly.**

**4. Wait for a few Minutes**
If you've recently made changes, give it some time before checking again.

**5. Review your complete repo/project**

- Make sure there are no typos or syntax errors.
- Look for any missing or incorrectly configured dependencies.
- Check for case sensitivity issues in file and folder names, as GitHub Pages is case-sensitive.

I hope it will help you.